# Jest configuration

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I'm adding Jest Testing framework to my React Native project. I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to get mock metadata: /Users/me/Documents/Development/project/node_modules/global/window.js
```

My test file looks like this:

```
import 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { MyComponent } from '../components/MyComponent'

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<MyComponent />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

And also the Jest configuration in my package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/", "/example/", "/lib/"],
    "testRegex": "(/tests/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(js|jsx)$",
    "automock": "true",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [ "lodash" ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!@exponent/ex-navigation",
      ")"
    ]
  }
```

I had a look over  http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html#content as suggested on the error prompted.

Answer (score 1):

I think something is wrong with your jest configuration in package.json.

Here is a sample jest config snippet:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "cacheDirectory": "./cache",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./app/utils/vendor"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 80
      }
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|react-navigation)"
    ]
  }
```

**preset**: The preset is a node environment that mimics the environment of a React Native app. Because it doesn’t load any DOM or browser APIs, it greatly improves Jest’s startup time.

**cacheDirectory**: It helps you greatly improve the test speed. It does so by creating cache of compiled modules so that next time it doesn’t have to compile the node_modules while running tests.

**coveragePathIgnorePatterns**: Define the files which want to skip for coverage reports.

**coverageThreshold**: Defines the threshold limit for all the tests to pass. If the coverage is less than the defined limit, the tests would fail. This helped us to keep a good amount of coverage at all point of time.

**transformIgnorePatterns**: We pass all the NPM modules here which needs to be transpiled. These modules are basically ES6/7 modules.

PS: I have written a blog on how to setup jest for react-native project. Here is the URL : http://rahulgaba.com/react-native/2017/05/19/Jest-test-suite-with-superpowers.html

Answer (score 0):

Set `"automock": "false"` in your package.json (automocking with the jest-react-native preset [isn't supported](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2188#issuecomment-263816847))